# How to write a conditional loop for a Ubuntu console program in C

Tags: c, linux

How would you or is it possible to write a conditional if loop in C in the ubuntu terminal. This is for a project I have to write in university.

I think the language is C from what I have been told.

I'll write my problem in pseudo code and any help would be great.

```
global x variable
global y variable

please enter X (x has to be a value between 1-100)
if anything other than 1-100 then repeat and ask for x again

once the value has been identified as 1-100
please enter Y
if anything other than 1-100 enter ask again

once the two values have been entered scan into a 2d array.
```

Example:

```
please enter x: d
please enter x: d
please enter x: 5
please enter y: f
please enter y: 5

1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5 
1 2 3 4 5
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Again my lecturer has said that this module is C and the console in Ubuntu Linux just to clarify.

Here is what I have so far; sorry for all the comments in it I have to comment to show what they all do as part of the task.

```
#include <stdio.h>  //this defines the library to use within c//  
#include <stdlib.h> //this defines the library to use within c//
#include <time.h>   //this defines the library to use within c//

int x; /*this sets the initial variables to program*/
int y; /*this sets the initial variables to program*/

int main(void){

printf("Please Enter Size X Of Array:");/*This is where the x limit of the array is set*/
scanf("%d",&x);
```

i want it to check here if the value entered is between 1-100 if its not it prints to enter size X of array again (Same for Y)

```
printf("\n");

printf("please Enter Size Y Of Array:");/*This is where the y limit of the array is set*/
scanf("%d",&y);

    int array[x][y];/*this sets the initial variables to program*/
```

Can anyone post how you would do this as it is not working when i try. Thanks.

Comment: try `help if` for conditional expressions, also `man test`, for loops try `help for` and `help while`. iirc ubuntu's default shell is either `dash` or `bash`. Try the man pages of those too, `man dash`.

Comment: Your pseudo-code seems sound; notice there are two identical tasks there that could be done with a re-usable function.  Try writing it in C.  Also: the fact that it is for in the ubuntu shell doesn't matter.  Just use `stdin` and `stdout` or commands explicitly for standard input and output, eg, `fgets()`, `scanf()`, `printf()`.  These work (more or less) the same way everywhere.

Comment: That pseudo-code is very clear. If `you` wrote that pseudo-code then you should have no problem coding it.

Comment: also the `if loop in C in the ubuntu terminal` does not make much sense. If you want to write `C` code then you need an editor and a compiler. If you want to write a script, the you can use the shell directly.

Comment: Decide if you wish to write a C program, compile it, and launch it from the shell in a terminal, or if you wish to write a script for the bash (or ash or dash or tcsh or whatever) shell interpreter you are running in that terminal.  Then do a web search for tutorials on C programming or bash (or whatever) scripting.

Comment: i have before and it just won't compile or just skips the loop and runs the rest of the program would it help if i posted what i had initially and comment where i want the if's added in?

Comment: @goldilocks: It matters, because on Windows, you constantly use conio.h, which isn't available on Linux. Without specifying "terminal", it could as well be a GUI-program.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: I guess if the lecturer tells you to do it in C, you do it in C, not in bash. The shell is only mentioned to indicate that it isn't a GUI-project.

Comment: @unknown: Nothing about this would *require* `conio.h` on MS, just `stdio.h`; identical code will work on both platforms.  I would imagine that is more appropriate for a uni assignment (avoiding unnecessary use of non-standard functions/libraries).

Comment: Are you writing a "command-line" or otherwise known as a console application in C?

Comment: the include parts are used later on in the program as i have a srand and normalisation function. 

sorry guys don't mean to be ignorant I'm not too sure 

basically i open terminal in unbuntu type touch assignment.c then nano assignment.c
not quite sure what that is all the lecturer said was this is C

Comment: Could someone answer this for me as i am sooo stuck and getting frustrated......

Comment: As this is a homework, generally you would not get full code but pointers. If you are stuck with checking the condition, look the pseudo code. You have to *loop* over a certain operation till a condition is satisfied, so how do you think you should approach it?

Answer (score 1):

```
do {
    printf("Please Enter Size X Of Array:");/*This is where the x limit of the array is set*/
    scanf("%d",&x);
} while (x<1 || x>100);
```

Comment: -1 because this has undefined behavior if a non-number is entered. You should check the return value of `scanf`. If it is not 1, then you must not look at the contents of x. (PS: and `fflush(stdout);` after the `printf` because there's no newline in the string).

Answer (score 0):

I'd write the loop like this:

```
 for (;;) {
     printf ("Please Enter Size X Of Array: ");
     fflush (stdout);
     if (scanf ("%d", &x) == 1 && x >= 1 && x <= 100) {
         break;
     }
     /* Read a character to prevent looping forever for non-numbers or EOF. */
     if (( x = getchar()) == EOF) {
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
     }
 }
```